# HTML: Image wont go to top :(

Tags: html, image

I feel like this should be a super simple fix but it's driving me crazy. I am trying to get this image to rest up against the top of the browser window but I'm getting this padding above the image that I can't get rid of.

I've tried a few things like setting padding to 0 and I've tried deleting everything but the  and I'm still getting the padding. Any help would be appreciated :)

http://twopairphoto.com/SlapFat/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <style>

    body{
      padding-top: 0px;
    }       
    div {  
      padding-top: 0px;
    }    
  </style>
</head>
<body background="SlapFatBG_sm.jpg">
<div id="container" align="center"><img src="slapfatsplash_sm.jpg" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set margin to 0 also:

```
body {
      padding-top: 0px;
      margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh margin! I knew it was something simple. Thanks so much guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `padding-top` in the div to the `margin-top`

That should help

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="margin: 0px auto;">
```

or

```
body {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

This will get rid of the margin on the top and bottom of the screen that is their by default. This will also center your content in most browsers as a result of setting the left and right margins to auto.

Answer (score 0):

You could try absolute positioning...

```
div {position:absolute; top:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px; //<---- Set body margin to 0px
}
```

Confirmed with Firefox.